# Information delivery through zigbee

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, robotics, zigbee

I am doing a project in which i have to measure the voltages of a given terminal and send it to other distant system through zigbee. My work plan is like this: I will use an arduino board and measure the voltage of the terminal. Then i will send that information to zigbee which is connected to Arduino. This zigbee will transmit the info to other zigbee and that zigbee when connected to system will display the voltage values. My problem is i have read that we have to use API configuration to send info automatically. But API will display the info in hexa decimal. But i want it to display the info as 'The voltage is 10.3456 volts' likewise. So any help from you guys. Also indicate if any loopholes are there in my workplan.

Comment: So, your specific question is how do you get from hexadecimal (binary) numbers to real-world units?

Comment: Yes. i want to know how to display it in normal words. Any solution??/

Comment: From your example I understand you (may) want to measure voltages more than 5 V. You will need a voltage divider for that, or you will fry the Arduino: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,13395.0.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the function itoa(). You can google an implementation if it's not available in your standard library (it usually isn't).

Answer (score -1):

In general terms, in order to convert from a "raw" binary ADC reading to the real-world value that it actually represents, you need to know how much of the real-world value one "count" of the ADC reading represents.

Most ADCs measure voltage between zero and some reference value, dividing that interval into some number of steps N, and produce an integer result J. The fraction J/N represents where in the measurement span the actual reading falls.
The number of steps is usually a power of two, where N = 2<sup>B</sup> and B is the number of bits that the ADC produces.

So, you need to know the reference voltage of the ADC and the number of bits it produces and you can compute the actual value being measured as V<sub>REF</sub> × J / 2<sup>B</sup>.

Note that if there is circuitry upstream of the ADC that is scaling the voltage in some way, or converting some other measurement into voltage, you also need to "invert" the operation of that circuitry in your calculation in order to get the original value being measured.

Comment: In Arduino this is achieved very easily with the map() function: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/map

Answer (score -2):

You don't need API mode unless you have many zigbees together. One coordinator and one "slave" with Arduino can be done in AT mode, which is much easier and allows you to send whatever you want in text format.
======= UPDATE=======

The X-CTU has a "terminal" tab; I assume you want to see the output there. Make sure the coordinator Zigbee is the one connected to X-CTU. (Coordinator Zigbee must have the function set "Coordinator AT", the other Zigbee, the "sender", must have the function set "Router/End device AT)

To check for the obvious bugs first: connect the arduino, without the XBEE shield, directly to the computer and check that it is in fact writing data on the serial port.

If all is ok: put the shield with the sender zigbee on the Arduino, turn it on, preferably with a separate power supply, not from USB. Connect the coordinator Zigbee to the computer and open X-CTU.

Check that you can communicate with the coordinator Zigbee from the X-CTU terminal: type +++ and you should get OK (this means you are in command mode); type ATMY and it should answer 0 because the coordinator's address is always zero. ATND should show you the sender Zigbee's details (the sender Zigbee is on, right?).

If these tests are OK, but you still don't get anything in the terminal window, then most probably the sender Zigbee is not transmitting correctly to the coordinator, i.e. the destination address of the sender Zigbee has been set wrong. To correct the addresses: Program the other Zigbee via X-CTU: set DH=0, DL=0, make sure the ID (network ID) is the same in both coordinator and sender, and "Save" the configuration (click the "Write" button).

Repeat the tests. If you still have problems, have a look at the resources under http://erion.elmasllari.com/in-the-trenches-with-xbee-resources-and-tips/ , especially the FAQ and the Cookbook, or ask again here.

Comment: So if i do the entire thing in AT mode with only 2 zigbees, the info sent by arduino to the zigbee can be seen in word format in a pc at a distant place?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the actual question, as clarified in the comments above.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: I understand the poster has difficulties with making his setup work the way he wants. ZigBee API mode is not easy to program, even with the required libraries. Compare this to AT mode where he can format the answer whichever way he wants, already in the Arduino, in decimal, with a simple Serial.print(). So, in my opinion, it has to do with what the poster wants to achieve. I believe in showing people how to solve their problems better, not how to create more bugs and ultimately give up.

Comment: Hey Thanks @Erion . I got it resolved.But the only problem i am getting is i cant display the words in the zigbee x-ctu window, like: " First input voltage is 3.8934 volts". Any solution for this??? Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly -- hope that helps!